# How can I find the website blocking settings on my router admin page?

Tags: router, blocking, administration

I would like to block some websites through my router. Going through the router's settings I cannot find the [page](https://kidslox.com/how-to/block-websites-on-wifi-router/) for it. As you see in the image below.

[image]

Any hints?

Model number: VX220-G2v

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look in Access Controls and Parental Controls.

Comment: How do you know your router has that feature? I've never used a router that had any such thing.

Comment: Your router may not support it.  It will help if you could include in the OP the router's model number so potential answerers can look up the manual.  As @John suggested, look in "Parental Controls" page.  Access control is for limiting access of connected devices to the LAN instead of device access to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Parental Controls setting.  Since you didn't specify the router's model number, I'm going to use an example from the tp-link [TL-WR841N user guide](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/tl-wr841n_v14/chapter-4-configure-the-router-in-wireless-router-mode#ug-sub-title-9):

1. Enable Parental Controls
2. Enter the MAC addresses
3. Enter the time range
4. Enter the URL to block

For more information on tp-link router Parental Controls, please see [their FAQ page](https://www.tp-link.com/ca/support/faq/2386/).

I realize that tp-link Parental Controls is not ideal for your need as there is no easy way to block websites for all devices.

Another method I recommend is to use a 3rd party filtering service and change the DNS servers of the router to use the ones provided by the filtering service.

Comment: Thanks but it does not have an URL option. please see the added image

Comment: @HandsomeNerd I think you need to enable it first and follow steps 2 and 3 for the option to appear.

Comment: I have tried, please see the added photo

Comment: @HandsomeNerd It seems your device doesn't have that option then.  You can use a [DNS/Content Filtering solution](https://geekflare.com/dns-content-filtering-software/).  CloudFlare has a free plan that seems to include URL blocking (don't know how many you can add).